# Android listview not working as expected

Tags: android, listview

I have this code that will eventually be populated from a database but to get it working first I have used the below code

```
  ListView mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>( );
        HashMap<String, Object> listItem;
        listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (int i = 0;i<=10;i++) {
            listItem.put("item", "orderTitles" + i);
            listItem.put("subitem", "orderDescriptions" + i);
            items.add(listItem);
        }
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), items, R.layout.list_item_format, new String[]{"item", "subitem"}, new int[]{R.id.itemTitle, R.id.itemDescription});
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is that the output to the list is saying only OrderTitles10 and OrderDescriptions10 (listed 10 times) instead of counting incrementally. What am I doing wrong

Comment: Why -1? its a valid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to this:

```
 ListView mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>( );
        HashMap<String, Object> listItem;

        for (int i = 0;i<=10;i++) {
            listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            listItem.put("item", "orderTitles" + i);
            listItem.put("subitem", "orderDescriptions" + i);
            items.add(listItem);
        }
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), items, R.layout.list_item_format, new String[]{"item", "subitem"}, new int[]{R.id.itemTitle, R.id.itemDescription});
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much that has worked perfectly _ I have had no luck with custom adapters, no tutorials on the seemed to work (hard to believe that's true, so it must be me). This worked great though as a work around.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `listItem` inside for loop to create and add new `HashMap` with both values in `ArrayList` :

```
    for (int i = 0;i<=10;i++) {
        listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        listItem.put("item", "orderTitles" + i);
        listItem.put("subitem", "orderDescriptions" + i);
        items.add(listItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> initialize listitem inside the loop and change the for loop condition like below

```
 for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
    listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    listItem.put("item", "orderTitles" + i);
    listItem.put("subitem", "orderDescriptions" + i);
    items.add(listItem);
}
```